# Tagging questions about `fastest` routes/means of transportation

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have a [budget](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) tag which can be used for questions mentioning money (which is the cheapest ...) in their title/body.

Would it make sense to create a tag for questions in which the OP asks for the fastest route/means of transportation?

Indeed [we have many such questions on TSE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=fastest%20route).

Comment: I suggest the tag [teleportation]

Comment: What about 'best way'? A mind-numbing 891 results.  Even 'authentic' returns twice as many as 'fastest route'.  'fastest' might encourage a parallel shift such that everyone feels that a superlative is needed for their question title. And then we're in the same place.   'Authentic', while not a superlative, is still a bit silly when you think about it. Who wants to eat phony food?

Comment: @GayotFow In hindsight `best` is a superlative too. I still think we need to find a way to tag these questions.

Comment: @JoErNanO, sure, but how to prevent a parallel shift?

Comment: @GayotFow I can't seem to come up with anything better than [tag:fastest-options], which sucks, or [tag:speed] which is meaningless. Help wanted. You're the native Yankee here. ;)

Comment: If Jeff Atwood is to be believed, the "best" is recorded in the vote count.  But "best" does not persist, e.g., the new rail link from Essex to Bucks.  And who ever asks for the 'most cumbersome' way to get to Paris? Or the slowest train to A'dam?  It's like, I need to use a really inefficient and unsafe and possibly illegal way to arrange for a taxi.

Comment: @pnuts I have not. We couldn't find the right tag at the time. Now I think that [tag:fastest-route-to] could do the trick.

Comment: @pnuts [tag:fast-travel]?